# Suppose that $F : X \longrightarrow Y$ is a function and $A$, $B$ are subsets of $Y$. Prove or disprove the following:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $F : X \longrightarrow Y$ is a function and $A$, $B$ are subsets of $Y$. Prove or disprove the following:

(a) Prove or Disprove: $F(A \cap B) = F(A) \cap F(B)$.

(b) What if $f$ is one-to-one?

Does this question have anything to do onto and one-to-oneness? It has been a while since I've worked with sets and subsets and was wondering if someone could lead me towards the correct answer? Thanks.

This was a homework review question for my proofs class.

Comment: what does & mean?

Comment: It's the opposite of the U (union) symbol.. Intersect? 
Can you make the edit for me if possible, I'm still a bit of a newbie.

Comment: I'm not sure what & means in this context, I could guess but will not because it is a nonstandard notation. Also F(A) F(B) are not meaningful unless A,B are subsets of the domain X.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$.

Define $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Let $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[2,3]$. Then $f(A\cap B)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ but $f(A)\cap f(B)=\{1\}$. The point is the following:

If you suppose that $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$ you can only guarantee that there exist $x_A\in A$ and $x_B\in B$ such that $f(x_A)=f(x_B)=y$, but if $f$ is not one-to-one, $x_A$ and $x_B$ may be different and they needn't belong to $A\cap B$. As you have seen before, $A$ and $B$ can even be disjoint. On the other hand, if $f$ is one-to-one $x_A=x_B$ and they (it) belongs to $A\cap B$, so $y\in f(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Alright I think I've got it.  Can you just quickly explain why when f is one-to-one everything holds?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "&" means $\cap$ and that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$.

Hint for (a): look at part (b) (that is, see what happens when $F$ is not one-to-one)

> If $F$ is not one-to-one, then there exists some elements $a$ and $b$ of $Y$ such that $F(a)=F(b)$. Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$. What happens?

But when $F$ is one-to-one, this cannot happen. What can you say about the preimage of elements of $F(A) \cap F(b)$?

Comment: From what I understand, because F is not one to one in case 1, there can exist multiple values of "x" that yield the same value of y.  This leads to the problem of (A & B) being null, while F(a) and F(b) are equal, producing a value at their intersections. (not null).  When F is one to one, we assume that if F(a) = F(b), then a = b, correct? :D

Answer (score 0):

ok. Put $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq} $ with $F(x) = x^2$. Put $A = [-1,0) $ and $B = (0, 1]$. Then $F(A) = (0,1] = F(B)$, but $ A \cap B = \varnothing $. hence $F(\varnothing) = \varnothing$